# Simplicial cochain representing the pullback of a class Poincaré dual of a submanifold

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-complexes, poincare-duality

Let $K$ be a simplicial complex of dimension $n$, $M$ be a topological manifold, and $f \colon |K|
\to M$ be a continuous map. Let $X$ be an embedded manifold in $M$ of codimension $n$, such that
$f(|K|) \cap X$ is a finite set of good points (i.e., a neighborhood of each point homeomorphic
to a disc where $f(|K|)$ and $X$ intersect as planes in general position), and their preimages lie in $|K \setminus
sk_{n-1} K|$.

Denote by $PD([X])$ the Poincaré dual of $X$ cohomology class lying in $H^n(M, \mathbb{Z}_2)$. It seems
correct that the pullback $f^*PD([X])$ in $H^n(K, \mathbb{Z}_2)$ is represented, for example, by a cochain
that associates to each $n$-simplex $A$ the count of points in $f(A) \cap X$ modulo two.

Is this statement true? Perhaps there is a formal proof of it somewhere, or did I miss something,
and it can be proved in just a few lines?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a special case of the first theorem of Section 3.6 of [WHITNEY STRATIFIED CHAINS AND COCHAINS](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1981-267-01/S0002-9947-1981-0621981-X/S0002-9947-1981-0621981-X.pdf).

Comment: I think a version of this is also in Bredon's Geometry and Topology text.

Comment: Thank you!

It seems that the theorem you refer to is stated only in the smooth category, and its connection
with a smooth structure on the manifold is quite strong, e.g., I assume the stratification uses the smooth
structure.

I tried to look at 'A geometric approach to homology theory' cited in the paper but couldn't find
something relevant to my question, at least at first glance.

Comment: @RyanBudney Thank you! I believe you're referring to Chapter 6, correct? I've been reviewing it but, unfortunately, haven't found the version you mentioned. Would you kindly provide additional details? I'm grateful for your help!

Comment: @Alex Apologies, I missed the topological manifold assumption. I think if you replace $M$ by a regular neighborhood of Euclidean space and then apply the theorem you might be able to extract your statement, but I have not checked.